# jQuery HowTo Toggle Animate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Hello I'm working to slide a DIV to the left (off the page). ...

I have the following which works:

```
$('.mybigbox').live('click', function() {
 leftDistance = $(this).attr('name'); // set px so I know how far
 $lefty.animate({left:leftDistance}) // Makes the slide
});
```

What what I want to happen, is on the first click it animates with the above, but on the next click it returns to default. (kind of like a toggle, on off button.

Ideas? thank you

Comment: that works? seems like there are errors there... but maybe i'm missing something.

Comment: The above slides the div to the left and is activated with a CLICK bind. but when I click again, I'd like to to return back to the orig state?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
var defaultLeftPosition = null;

$("#yourdiv").toggle(function(){
    if (defaultPosition != null)
        defaultLeftPosition = $(this).offset().left;
    // do your code for animating to the new position
},
function(){
    // get default position from variable defaultLeftPosition and set left 
    // to that inside animate
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### [See Demo Here](http://jsbin.com/eqeza3)

---

If I understand you correctly, try this:

```
$('.mybigbox').live('click', function() {
   $lefty.animate({width:'toggle');
});
```